# What is the name of this series? $3$, $4$, $6$, $9$, $13$, $18$, $24$, $\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The first term is $3$ and difference between to two terms is not constant, as
$$\begin{align}
        \text{2nd term} &= 3+1=4 \\
        \text{3rd term} &= 4+2=6 \\
        \text{4th term} &= 6+3=9 \\
\end{align}$$
and so on. The series is
$$3, 4, 6, 9, 13, 18, 24, \ldots$$

Comment: Have you tried the OEIS?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yeah edited :)

Comment: This is just the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) plus 3.

Comment: These are the dimensions of the maximal compact subgroups $S(O(n) \times O(3))$ of the indefinite special orthogonal groups $SO(n, 3)$.

Comment: It is a quadratic progression.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is [OEIS $A152950$](https://oeis.org/A152950) (if this counts as name, but there is no specific attached at OEIS). There is not really anything of particular interest about this series, as we can explicitly write down

> $$a_n=3+\frac{n(n-1)}2$$

(As pointed out by *eyeballfrog*, these are just the triangular numbers plus three)

Comment: the difference between two terms is not constant, but the difference between the differences between two terms is, so does that mean $a_n$ is a quadratic function of $n$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Well, yes. It can be oberserved from the explicit formula. However, the procedure you describe can be used to deduce Gauss' Summation Formula for instance. As this sequence is nothing more than the triangular numbers (plus $3$) a similiar argument works.